# .NET buffered sql read

Tags: .net, sql, c#-4.0

I'm trying to make an export of big data (3.000.000 rows). The problem is that the process takes too much ram. It's a 32 bit application and takes almost 1.5 GB.
In java I knew there is a possibility to read row per row from a query without saving the result in ram.
It would also be ok to limit the buffer size of this single query.

Does someone has any ideas how I can archive this?

I'm currently using .NET Framework 4.0, but in case I would change to 4.5.1 if this could help.

Answer (score 1):

You want the [DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

Comment: I'm already using it, and I don't want to fetch, because it would be extreeeemly slow